# AWS Lambda function connection problems

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sendinblue

I´m trying to build few lambda fucntions, first one, to send emails through SendinBlue using [sib-api-v3-sdk](https://pypi.org/project/sib-api-v3-sdk/) and another one to get historical etf data from Investing using [investpy](https://investpy.readthedocs.io/).

Well, I have problems with both functions, didn't work... I´ve tried changing the time out to 10 min or more, but nothing happend, always the same...

SendinBlue function shows this:

```
    Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f151ca80100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out')': /v3/emailCampaigns
```

And Investpy function shows this:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.investing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /instruments/HistoricalDataAjax (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f21949626a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Both works fine in local.

The functions:
SendinBlue

```
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
import os
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('## EMPEZAMOS')
    logger.info('# Configure API key authorization: api-key #')
    configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
    configuration.api_key['api-key'] = 'MY-API-KEY'
    logger.info('# create an instance of the API class')
    api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.EmailCampaignsApi(sib_api_v3_sdk.ApiClient(configuration))
    list_id = my_list
    email_list = sib_api_v3_sdk.UpdateEmailCampaignRecipients(list_ids=[list_id])
    email_sender = sib_api_v3_sdk.CreateEmailCampaignSender(name='My_name', email='My_mail')
    email_campaigns_create = sib_api_v3_sdk.CreateEmailCampaign(sender=email_sender, subject='Prueba Lambda', reply_to='My_mail', name='Prueba AWS Lambda', html_content='Hola esto es una prueba desde Lambda', recipients=email_list)
    logger.info('## CREAR NUEVAS CAMPAÑAS ##')
    try:
        # Create an email campaign
        api_response = 
        api_instance.create_email_campaign(email_campaigns_create)
        print(api_response)
        logger.info('# CAMAPÑA CREADA')
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling EmailCampaignsApi- 
        >create_email_campaign: %s\n" % e)
        logger.error("ERROR: PROBLEMA AL CREAR CAM")
        logger.error(e)
    return print(api_response)
```

Investpy

```
import investpy
import pymysql
from db_parametros import *
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys
import logging

start_time = time.time()

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#Conectamos a BBDD
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=bbdd, connect_timeout=60)
except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit()
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        #Sacamos la relacion de datos que necesitamos para hacer la llamada a Investing
        query = 'SELECT  a.id, a.nombre, a.ISIN, i.name, i.full_name, i.stock_exchange, i.country 
FROM Activos a LEFT JOIN Paises p ON a.pais=p.id LEFT JOIN Regiones r ON a.region=r.id LEFT JOIN TipoMercados m ON a.mercadoInvesting=m.id LEFT JOIN Investing i ON a.isin=i.isin AND i.stock_exchange=m.nombre ORDER BY a.id;'
    tabla = cur.execute(query)

    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    #print(df)
    x= len(df)
    #print(x)
    y =0

    for x in range (0, len(df)):
        while y <= x:
            try:
                print('ETF nº: '+ str(x+1) + ' -- Se esta cargando: ' + str(df.at[x, 'nombre']))
                df_data = investpy.get_etf_historical_data(etf=df.at[x, 'name'],
                                            country=df.loc[x, 'country'],
                                            from_date='01/01/2000',
                                            to_date='01/01/2022')
                df_data = df_data.reset_index()
                df_data = df_data[['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
                df_data['idActivo'] = x+1
                #print(df_data)
                if x ==0:
                    cur.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE CotizacionesActivos')
                    #con.execute('')
                    df_data.to_sql('CotizacionesActivos', conn, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
                else:
                    df_data.to_sql('CotizacionesActivos', conn, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
            except ValueError:
                print('ETF nº: '+ str(x+1) + ' -- **ERROR ** No se ha posido cargar: ' + str(df.at[x, 'nombre']))
                pass
            y += 1
        



    print("--- Completada carga en BBDD en %s minutos ---" % ((time.time() - start_time)/60))
return
```

Comment: Is your lambda running in a VPC? If so, I'd bet you don't have access to the internet from the subnet you're running in.

Comment: Hi @JasonWadsworth , I need to create a new subnet? sorry but im pretty new in aws and lambda...

Comment: You need to re-read Jason's question. Is the Lambda configured to run in VPC? If so, why? Do you actually need it to run in VPC? If the answer's "I don't know" then the answer is probably "no" and you can re-deploy it outside of VPC and it will work because it will then have a route to the internet.

Comment: What jarmod said. I'm trying to narrow down the problem, not necessarily answer it. If you are in a VPC I (or someone else) can give you options related to that. If it's not in a VPC then it's a completely different problem.

Comment: SendinBlue function is working know, but Investpy not. I asume that this function needs to be connect to a VPC because it needs to do a query in a rds... Now i need to create a new subnet??